# Attempting add facebook login but app crashes android

Tags: java, android, facebook-login

I'm trying to add facebook login with a login button in a fragment. 
When I try to run my app, it crashes and I get the following errors in my logcat

```
02-20 15:30:34.838  12503-12503/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.loomius.loomius, PID: 12503
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loomius.loomius/com.loomius.loomius.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.loomius.loomius.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: Unexpected CallbackManager, please use the provided Factory.
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.registerCallback(LoginManager.java:151)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.registerCallback(LoginButton.java:445)
            at com.loomius.loomius.facebookLogin.onCreateView(facebookLogin.java:36)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4803)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:41)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.loomius.loomius.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.loomius.loomius" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        </application>
</manifest>
```

and here is my `MainActivity.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
        // especially, if you're using Facebook UI elements.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

My `activity_main.xml` file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment android:name="com.loomius.loomius.facebookLogin"
        android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my `fragment_facebook_login.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.loomius.loomius.facebookLogin">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and finally my `facebookLogin.java`

```
public class facebookLogin extends Fragment {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook_login, container, false);

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        // If using in a fragment
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        // Other app specific specialization

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
             @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("facebook_login", "The login was a success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("facebook_login", "The login got canceled midway");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.d("facebook_login", "The login got failed");
        }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

I tried following [the guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) in the documentation by facebook. Sorry for the code dump, I'm new to android and I have no idea what's causing my app to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();` put this code below

`FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());`.

You have to initialze the callbackManager .

Cheers!!

Comment: but none of the registered callbacks are getting called, I can't see the logs....

Answer (score 2):

you also need

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

for callbacks to work